# Wkhtmltopdf. Generate folder

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

How using the program wkhtmltopdf I convert the entire folder with html files?

Let's say there are 10,000 html files in the folder, and I need to make 10,000 pdf out of them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that directly with wkhtmltopdf, you will need some external logic to handle going through your files.

This could be a shell script, or it could be a portion of the program you are writing. If you simply have a task that states "convert these files to pdf" and you are running on a standard Linux server, I would advise you to write a shell script that loops over the files and executes wkhtmltopdf for each file separately.